# Reading and filtering file in parallel in Python

Tags: python, readfile

I have a simple script that first reads a CSV table (95MB, 672343 lines) and creates 5 list from it (chrs, type, name, start, end). Then it opens another file (37MB, 795516 lines), reads each line and compares it to the  and if everything is ok - writes the string to an output file. This takes a lot of time.

```
for line in inputFile:
    line = line[0:len(line) - 1]
    arr = line.split('\t')
    for i in xrange(len(chrs)):
        if (arr[0]==chrs[i]) and (int(arr[1])>=int(starts[i])) and  (int(arr[1])<=int(ends[i])):
            outputFile.write(chrs[i]+ '\t' + types[i] + '\t' + starts[i] + '\t' + ends[i] + '\t' + names[i] + '\t' + line + '\n');
```

I was wondering if it is possible to run this in parallel, I have an access to the server, where I can run up to 10 processes at once.

Comment: You probably don't need to make that copy of `line`.  Maybe you could read through both files at the same time, in lockstep, so you don't have to store anything.

Comment: *Just a suggestion:* I believe you would be performing this action only once a day (may be via cron job?). You do not have to multi-process it just because your server may execute 10 processes in parallel. You would be increasing the complexity of problem, even though you don't need it. If it is real-time task, then it is a different thing.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh is it more efficient to go through the file several times than to go through lists?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, but there are many small things that seem off. First of all, have you tried using the built-in `csv` module instead of splitting and concatenating everything yourself?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri actually I am doing a research project and I do not think that I will have to use this script a lot (maybe one more time on another file and that's all), but I want to get the result asap. I started computations yesterday and went through only 70,000 lines by now, so it will take 10 days to get the result, it's crazy

Comment: @GeorgSchölly no, thank you for your advice! Do you think it will speed up the computations a lot?

Comment: @user2080209: No, I don't think so. I'm having a look at your code. The culprit is probably the quadratic running time.

Comment: @user2080209 I'm a little confused about what output you want.  Could you be a little clearer on how the lines in the output are built and how many of them there should be?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh well, actually there is the first file, that contains information about the genes (it is converted into lists), and the second file (inputFile) contains information about mutations, and I want to get information about mutations that are inside genes + information about these genes. This is why output looks strange, but it is exactly what I need. I do not know how many lines should be in output file, it's one of the questions I want to answer on with this code.

Comment: Can you make any assumptions about the order of the lines in either of the input files (i.e. are they sorted by anything)? Also, is there any overlap in the `starts[i]`->`ends[i]` ranges?

Comment: @glibdud I can assume that it will be not more than ~50,000 lines in the output. Both files are ordered by chr, but differently. First file has (chr1, chr2 ,...) and second one (chr10, chr11, ...,chr1, chr2,...), but I think I could reorder them. Starts and Ends are in the same ranges, ends[i] = starts[i] + 10~10000.

Comment: Are there any overlapping `starts[i]`->`ends[i]` ranges, like for example `starts[1]=1; ends[1]=5; starts[2]=3; ends[2]=10`?

Comment: @glibdud in most cases each line's starts will be higher that the previous but then they will again start for 1, like 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,... There can be overlapping starts and ends ranges

Comment: One more question... what's the highest possible value for `starts` or `ends`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133365/discussion-between-glibdud-and-user2080209).

Comment: @glibdud about 200,000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you iterate 672343 * 795516 = 534'859'613'988 times, this is a lot. You need a smarter solution.

So we found out that the problem is that we look at too much data, we need to change that. One way to do this is to try and be smart. Maybe create a dictionary where the key corresponds to `chr` so we only need to check against those entries. But then we haven't dealt with `start` and `end` yet. Maybe there's a smart way to do that too…

This starts to look a lot like a database. So if it is a database, maybe we should treat it as one. Python comes with sqlite3 included.

Here's a solution, but there are countless other possibilities out there.

```
import sqlite3
import csv

# create an in-memory database
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

# create the tables
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE t1 (
    chr   TEXT,
    type  TEXT,
    name  TEXT,
    start INTEGER,
    end   INTEGER
);""")

# if you only have a few columns, just name them all,
# if you have a lot, maybe just put everything in one
# column as a string
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE t2 (
    chr TEXT,
    num INTEGER,
    col3,
    col4
);""")

# create indices on the columns we use for selecting
c.execute("""CREATE INDEX i1 ON t1 (chr, start, end);""")
c.execute("""CREATE INDEX i2 ON t2 (chr, num);""")

# fill the tables
with open("comparison_file.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # sqlite takes care of converting the number-strings to numbers
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", reader)

with open("input.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # sqlite takes care of converting the number-strings to numbers
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", reader)

# now let sqlite do its magic and select the correct lines
c.execute("""SELECT t2.*, t1.* FROM t1
             JOIN t2 ON t1.chr == t2.chr
             WHERE t2.num BETWEEN t1.start AND t1.end;""")

# write result to disk
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in c:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

## Python coding tips

Here's how I would have written your original code.

```
import csv

# used to be chrs[], type[], name[], start[], end[]
comparisons = []
with open("comparison_file.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for chr, type, name, start, end in reader:
        comparisons.append([chr, type, name, int(start), int(end)])

with open("output.csv", 'wb') as out_file, \
     open("input.csv", 'rb') as in_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)

    for line in reader:
        for comp in comparisons:
            chr, _, _, end, start = *comp
            if line[0] == chr and \
               int(line[1]) >= start and \
               int(line[2]) >= end:
                writer.writerow(comp + line)
```

#### Remarks 1

```
line = line[0:len(line) - 1]
```

can be written as

```
line = line[:-1]
```

#### Remark 2

Instead of

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
for i in xrange(len(my_list)):
    # do something with my_list[i]
```

you should do:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
for item in my_list:
    # do something with item
```

If you need the index, combine it with `enumerate()`.

Comment: Remark 1 is not quite right... the equivalent is `line = line[:-1]`, but I'm guessing what he's trying to do is chop the trailing newline off, so `line = line.rstrip('\n')` might be more appropriate.

Comment: I am 'she' by the way, maybe this would explain a lot :))

Comment: @user2080209: I don't think so. I've updated this answer with some code where I leverage the built-in sqlite database. Can you try it out on your data?

Comment: @GeorgSchölly OMG! It worked extremely fast! Thank you so much!! You are genius! :)

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple of things that might speed up progress a bit, starting with rearranging the data from the first file.

Instead of turning it into 5 individual `list`s, make it a `dict` of `list`s of `tuple`s with the `chr` value as key:

```
import csv
import collections
import bisect

# Use a defaultdict so we don't have to worry about whether a chr already exists
foobars = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('file1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for (chrs, typ, name, start, end) in rdr:
        foobars[chrs].append((int(start), int(end), typ, name))
```

Then sort each list in `foobars` (which you should obviously rename to something appropriate to your task), which will sort first by `start` value since we placed that first in the tuple:

```
for lst in foobars.values():
    lst.sort()
```

Now to process your second file:

```
for line in inputFile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    arr = line.split('\t')
    arr1int = int(arr[1])
    # Since we rearranged our data, we only have to check one of our sublists
    search = foobars[arr[0]]
    # We use bisect to quickly find the first item where the start value
    # is higher than arr[1]
    highest = bisect.bisect(search, (arr1int + 1,))
    # Now we have a much smaller number of records to check, and we've 
    # already ensured that chr is a match, and arr[1] >= start
    for (start, end, typ, name) in search[:highest]:
        if arr1int <= end:
            outputFile.write('\t'.join((arr[0], typ, str(start), str(end), name, line)) + '\n')
```

The `bisect.bisect()` line deserves a bit of extra explanation. If you have a sorted sequence of values, `bisect` can be used to find where a new value would be inserted into the sequence. We use that here to find the first value in the list where `start` is greater than our `arr[1]` (take a minute to think about how those concepts are related). The odd-looking `(arr1int + 1,)` value is simply making sure we include all entries where `start == arr[1]` and converting it to a tuple so that we're comparing like values.

This should almost certainly improve performance of your code. By just how much I'm not really qualified to say.

*Without the input data I couldn't really test this code, so there are almost certainly small errors. Hopefully they'll be easy enough to fix.*